# How to create multiple context menus on right click depending on which object was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using an event attached to $(document)
I tried changing it to different elements on the page, but nothing happens.

This is my starting code for a basic context menu

```
    $(document).bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($(".context-menu") != null) {
            $(".context-menu").remove();
        }
        $("<div class='context-menu'>" +
            "<ul>" +
            "<a href=javascript:null onclick=''><li>Do Something</li></a>" +
            "</ul>"+
            "</div>")
            .appendTo("body")
            .css({ top: event.pageY + "px", left: event.pageX + "px" });
    });
    $(document).bind("click", function (event) {
        $(".context-menu").remove();
    });
```

**Clarification**

I am not trying to create a context menu. I am trying to create multiple ones, each one is triggered by right clicking a different element.

For instance, if you right-click a div, you get a context menu with the ability to change the div's color, if you right-click on the document you get a different context menu, and if you right-click on the header, yet a different context menu.

Can this be done?

This is my attempt that doesn't work

```
    $(document).bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

    });
    $(document).bind("click", function (event) {
        $(".context-menu").remove();
    });

    $("#divID").mousedown(function (e) {
            if (e.button == 2) {
                if ($(".context-menu") != null) {
                    $(".context-menu").remove();
                }
                $("<div class='context-menu'>" +
                    "<ul>" +
                    "<a href=javascript:null onclick=''><li>Do Somthing</li></a>" +
                    "</ul>" +
                    "</div>")
                    .appendTo("divID")
                    .css({ top: event.pageY + "px", left: event.pageX + "px" });
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
```

Comment: Works fine in my chrome 40....

Comment: Is there an event for *bind("contextmenu")*?

Comment: Seems strange to wrap `li` with `a` in `ul`... not sure that is even valid.

Comment: It's probably not, but that's not where my problem stems from :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fiddle maybe help you!!!

[Just Sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/jckim0414/8msg6bfy/2)

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
});

$(document).on("mousedown","#divID",function (e) {
    if ($(".context-menu").length != 0) {
        $(".context-menu").remove();
    }
    if (e.button == 2) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $("<div class='context-menu'>" +
             "<ul>" +
             "<a href=javascript:null onclick=''><li>Do Somthing</li></a>" +
             "</ul>" +
              "</div>")
        .appendTo($(this))
             .css({ top: event.pageY + "px", left: event.pageX + "px" });
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

[Jquery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/#example-9)

**bind event parent but targeting child**

Answer (score 0):

Without writing out a whole script for you, you want to get

`e.target.tagName` or `event.srcElement.tagName` (depending on browser)

from the event listener.

This will give you A, IMG, TEXTAREA etc.